# How to better position Next/Back button in shiny glide, in order to eliminate large white space?

Tags: css, r, shiny, widget

The Shinyglide package is just what I need, using a carousel for grouped radio buttons giving the user many choices for data parsing.

However, the "Next" (and "Back") button occupies a large white space. I'd like to shift the button in line with the glide row (see image at bottom). Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a CSS trick? Reading through the Glide manual, the only choices are "top" and "bottom".

If moving the Next/Back button isn't possible, a secondary option is to insert (a somewhat superfluous) line of text but in line with the Next/Back buttons, to at least cover up the annoyingly large white space.

The actual panel this is for has much more information presented than in this example, so I'm trying to make the page as clean as possible.

Please see image at bottom that better explains what I'm trying to do.

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(div(style = "margin-top:15px"),
      strong("Input choices shown in row below, click ´Next´ to see more choices:"),
        column(12, glide(
           height = "25",
           controls_position = "top",
           screen(
             div(style = "margin-top:10px"),
             wellPanel(    
               radioButtons(inputId = 'group1',
                 label = NULL,
                 choiceNames = c('By period','By MOA'), 
                 choiceValues = c('Period','MOA'),
                 selected = 'Period',
                 inline = TRUE
                 ),
               style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;"
               )
          ),
          screen(
            div(style = "margin-top:10px"),
            wellPanel(    
              radioButtons(inputId = 'group2',
                label = NULL,
                choiceNames = c('Exclude CT','Include CT'), 
                choiceValues = c('Exclude','Include'),
                selected = 'Exclude',
                inline = TRUE
                ),
             style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;"
             )
          )
         )
        )
      ),
    DTOutput("plants")
  ) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plants <- renderDT({iris %>% datatable(rownames = FALSE)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom control element with `custom_controls`, and then have it hover over the displayed screen on the top right with a container set to absolute positioning. Setting a limited width for the container will ensure that the back button won't fly too far out.

Something along these lines:

```r
glide(custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()), ...)

# Somewhere in the UI
tags$style(
  ".glide-controls { position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 15px; width: 160px; }"
)
```

Just make sure to also set `controls_position = "bottom"` so that the controls hover *over* the screen content, rather than under it.

A minimal example app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h3("Simple shinyglide app"),
  tags$style(
    ".glide-controls { position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 15px; width: 160px; }"
  ),
  glide(
    custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()),
    screen(wellPanel(p("First screen."))),
    screen(wellPanel(p("Second screen.")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: glide controls hovering over screen]

Comment: That is beautiful, THANK YOU! I posted that question thinking the chance that it gets a good response is remote. I am having a very difficult time with HTML/CSS. R has been much easier for me to get my head around, the logic just makes sense for most functions. But when it comes to HMTL/CSS, forget it, I am lost and getting no better at it even with time!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! And yeah, CSS especially can be tricky in my experience, too.